# Duplicate detection rule across the BUs in MS CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I have couple of BUs to separate the data records from one BU to another BU & I have duplicate detection rule enabled.

Issue is if in other BU I create a record which exists on another BU then it doesn't detect duplicate.

Is detection rule works BU specific or base rule has some issue?

**Update**

I have one super user who can see all other BUs data & that user could see duplicated records.

Comment: You have to take into account that duplicates can only be considered if the user creating duplicate a record can **see** the existing record because she needs to be able to merge or edit. This is obviously not the case in your scenario.

Comment: @Filburt No, normal user will not merge or edit the record but issue is when a super user (who has access to both the BUs) sees the records. All right, so, you are saying that duplicate detection works only within User's scope/access level?